# Cached framework variable accessible in template

Tags: php, caching, fat-free-framework

When I set cached fat-free variable

`$this->f3->set('memFilterYear', $years, 3600);`

this variable is not accessible in template. I need to set another variable like this

`$this->f3->set('tempFilterYear', $this->f3->get('memFilterYear'));`

tempFilterYear is accessible in template. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: what version do you use? I cannot see any hint the code why this should not work.

Comment: latest version 3.6.2

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue... it's working fine here.. maybe it's something else in your code?!

Comment: I have set cache variable in config.ini
`CACHE="memcache=localhost:11211"`
and in Controller i have function render and there is
`if(!$this->f3->exists('memFilterYear'))`
`$this->f3->set('memFilterYear', $years, 3600);`

Comment: I made another test and it appears to be true.. the cached variable isn't available in the template by default.. you need to request it from cache before, because the Template only receives a shadow copy of the currently loaded variables.

Comment: ok thanks. Is there any function to request it from cache? Do I have to use another variable?

Comment: well within the template itself, you could use `{{F3::get('memFilterYear')}}` to get the variable